# The icons for PDF files are huge! Other than resizing them manually, are there any icon packs that will make them smaller?

Tags: unity, 16.04, themes, icons

Here's what I'm talking about:

[image]

The icons for PDFs are so much bigger than all other icons, no matter the theme--be it the default one, or Paper, or Flatabulous. Why is this? And are there any icon packs that make them the same size as other icons? I don't want to have to manually resize the icon of every PDF I drag to my desktop to make my desktop look even.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Thanks.

Comment: https://i.imgflip.com/15jfkm.jpg

Comment: +1, I also want to know this. I'm not sure if your question "Why is this?" is meant to be taken literally, but in case it is: It's because the icon is a preview of the first page of the actual document and thus, the aspect ratio has to match.

Comment: Like @fiksdal said, it's shaping the actual preview of the PDF. That's why icon packs don't change it. Since the previews are taller than normal icons, they look a lot bigger. You might be able to turn off the preview and just use a preset icon, but I'm not sure how that would be done.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know; this is true. I don't know why I didn't realize this before posting--I guess I didn't look at the icons too closely. I would prefer not to have the first page previews, so if I can change all PDF icons to one type of icon, I'd be content. That's how it is in Windows with Foxit Reader.

Answer (score 1):

Since part of your question was "Why is this?",  I'll answer that part. It's because the icon is a preview of the first page of the actual document and thus, the aspect ratio has to match.

This obviously doesn't answer the most important part of the question,  namely how to change it. So this only answers part of your question.